# Firebase Issue: Step 4: Run your app to verify installation

Tags: android, firebase

[image]I am trying to create my first project using Firebase, however, when I reach step 4 "Run your app to verify installation" nothing happens. How can I fix this?

```
dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you followed the instructions, then you just need to run the app on a device connected to the internet; an emulator might work just fine, too.

Make sure to add code to use firebase; read, write, authenticate, or whatever else.

you can [read here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more information how to go about it.

As for step 4, you really can just skip it. It's not necessary.

Comment: I am trying to access the database rules but on the project there is just an option to "continue setup"

Comment: @SKdev, you can skip step 4 in right lower corner. It's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue recently, what worked for me was adding:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the top of the app level build.gradle file, above android, so for example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //Add this line here

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
...
```